# Edit Word documents and track changes using Python

Tags: python, ms-word

Suppose I have two Word documents, V1, and V2. I'd like to edit V1 to become V2.
Currently, I manually edit V1 line by line in Microsoft Word according to V2 and track my changes so there is a history of edits.

Is there a way to automate this process using code, preferrably in Python? I see there is a python-docx package, but I'm not sure that is the right way to approach this so I'm looking for some inspiration. Perhaps there is another API or VBA way to do this? It does NOT need to be perfect, just a script that can save a big chunk of the work.

The goal is to essentially create an "editor" that can change a paragraph of text to be like another paragraph by actually "editing" (inserting/deleting/replacing where necessary) word by word instead of completely copypasting a paragraph and replacing the entire paragraph.

The key is to see the history of tracked changes once I reopen the updated V1 in MS Word.

Comment: It sounds like what you're looking for is not literally a way to "edit V1 to become V2"; rather, you're looking for a way to produce a list of changes that would be required to take you from V1 to V2

Comment: @BenGrossmann yes, perhaps that's one way to frame the problem. Once I have this list of changes, I can go through it and edit V1 using python while setting a "tracked changes" attribute using python-docx or something of the like. What's the best method to produce this list of changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seem to have found a solution. Unfortunately, Python is not the way to go about this. Aspose.Words seems to support track revisions in Word; however, there is an expensive commercial license involved.

The easiest way to accomplish something I want is through VBA as it is built into Word and you can enable/disable revisions tracking as needed. The key is to use difflib or something similar to get opcodes between 2 paragraphs and then apply them via VBA.